# Programmatically hide views if it is shown. Show views if it is hidden

Tags: android, android-activity, view

My button use code that shows and hides the views:

```
    public void onClick (View v){ 

      if (What code you need to enter here to determine hidden views or shown)
      {  
          testActivity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
      else
      {
          testActivity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
  }
```

What code I need to add in the "if()", so that clicking on my button was checked condition. If the activity is hidden, it should be shown, and Vice versa. If the views is shown, hide it.

Comment: See http://steveliles.github.io/is_my_android_app_currently_foreground_or_background.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing since you are using `setVisibility`, that you want to check the visibility of a `View` , not an `Activity`.

In that case you just use `getVisibility()` 
(I used != cause the visibility could be IINVISIBLE as well, change per your needs) :

```
public void onClick (View v){ 

  if (testActivity.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
  {  
      testActivity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

  }
  else
  {
      testActivity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
} });
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't understand why, but only that removed the answer of a man who has solved my problem. Here is his response, and this code works:

```
  public void onClick (View v){ 

  if ((testActivity.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE))
  {  
      testActivity.setVisibility(View.GONE);

  }
  else
  {
      testActivity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

  }
```